# How to safely run my MacBook Pro (2014) as a server without damaging the battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I've been using my MacBook Pro 2014 as a Plex Server for a few years (sometime not switched off), but charger was always plugged in.

I think that the "always plugged in" killed the battery and now my Macbook doesn't start up.

I'll try to replace the battery with iFixIt kit.

But I was wondering on how could I avoid to quickly damage the battery, while keeping it plugged to its charger.

Do you know some way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batteries don't last forever, no matter how you treat them. Chances are that a nearly 10-year-old battery will fail, whether it's plugged in all the time, or not.

You can expect a replacement to last for several years. You could try using one of those third-party utilities that stops charging at 80%; but I believe their influence is overstated. (Assuming that Apple's own Battery Optimization doesn't work on your model.)

Time kills all batteries in the end....